# Mysql - where clause slower than full scan

Tags: mysql

Query A

```
Select id from jobs;

| 55966 |
| 55971 |
+-------+
10705 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Query B

```
Select id from jobs where status = 0;
| 55966 |
| 55971 |
+-------+
7933 rows in set (**20.22 sec**)
```

There IS an index on status.

```
mysql> explain select id from jobs where status = 0;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | jobs  | ALL  | status        | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10705 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)


mysql> show profile for query 1;
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| Status                         | Duration  |
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| starting                       |  0.000023 |
| checking query cache for query |  0.000039 |
| checking permissions           |  0.000006 |
| Opening tables                 |  0.000008 |
| System lock                    |  0.000004 |
| Table lock                     |  0.000016 |
| init                           |  0.000021 |
| optimizing                     |  0.000007 |
| statistics                     |  0.000904 |
| preparing                      |  0.000023 |
| executing                      |  0.000003 |
| Sending data                   | 19.751547 |
| end                            |  0.000009 |
| query end                      |  0.000002 |
| freeing items                  |  0.001561 |
| storing result in query cache  |  0.000122 |
| logging slow query             |  0.000002 |
| logging slow query             |  0.000002 |
| cleaning up                    |  0.000003 |
+--------------------------------+-----------+

mysql> show index from jobs;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

| jobs  |          1 | status   |            1 | status      | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| jobs  |          1 | date     |            1 | dateinit    | A         |        1784 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I dont understand why Query B takes 20 seconds while Query A takes 0 . Index on "status". Same result on prod and dev. server.

Comment: 0.00 second sounds like the query was cached. Are you flushing the cache between tests?

Comment: RESET QUERY CACHE; select id from nsync.jobs; -> 10705 rows in set (0.00 sec) . Still same result : (

Comment: Hmm. If all the time is "sending data", what's the query time when you ask for just a `COUNT()` matching the query instead of the rows?

Comment: can you please use `EXPLAIN` statement in front of your queries and then edit your question with results of it?

Comment: Here I added the explain. the select count(*) where status = 0; takes 0 seconds. The select count(id) takes 20 seconds. Bizarre bizarre.

Comment: It *is* so bizarre. Let's rule more stuff out. `REPAIR TABLE jobs`!

Comment: it's not bizarre, it's poor indexing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the index to both columns `(status, id)`

As I see it, you don't have any index on id

The [ANSI standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (look for "`Scalar expressions   125`") states that `COUNT(*)` give the row count of a table: it is intended to be optimised from the start.

> If COUNT(*) is specified, then the result is the cardinality of T.

This is why `COUNT(*)` is far quicker then `COUNT(id)`. `COUNT(*)` can use the `status` index. `COUNT(id)` won't use this index and there is no other valid index

What is the clustered index, and what is the PK? You have *both* (even if the same index), right?

Comment: This is exactly it. I have an index on id only.. but no index with status and id... now i understand the difference. It's working like a charm. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Benjamin: Is id the clustered index/PK? If it is, then you shouldn't need the composite index because if how indexes are structured

Comment: Yes it is the primary Key. What is a "clustered index"

Answer (score 1):

0.00 seconds sounds like the query was probably cached. That being said, a query for the `id` of a table can be answered straight from the primary key index (i.e, without looking at the table data at all!), while a query with a `WHERE` clause requires the database to actually read the rows.

Comment: Select country from jobs; 10705 results in 0 seconds

Comment: Select country from jobs where status = 0; 7933 results in 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

There is an index on `status`, but once MySQL had determined which rows have `status = 0`, there is a call, for each row, to find its id. If you `create index idx_jobs_status_id on jobs (status, id);` I predict that 20 seconds will go way down.

Comment: That's it! Working now. Thank you very much. Now I understand why the index takes on several value...