# whats faster, count(*) or count(table_field_name) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [COUNT(*) vs. COUNT(1) vs. COUNT(pk): which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better)

I want to retrieve the count from a select query.

What is faster: `count(*)` or `count(table_field_name)`?

I want to know which way is faster for performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721944/mysql-where-clause-slower-than-full-scan/6722067#6722067 and [COUNT(*) vs. COUNT(1) vs. COUNT(pk): which is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649 many others. And DBA.SE http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-colu/2512#2512

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is `Count(field)` returns count of NOT NULL values in the field, whether `COUNT(*)` returns COUNT of rows.
`COUNT(*)` in MyIsam should be faster.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Answer (score 0):

at least on MyISAM tables `count(*)` should be faster than `count(fliedname)` as it allows mysql to use an index (the primary key most times) to do the counting. if the given fieldname is the primary key, it wont make any difference.

using `*`, mysql **wont** be so dump to "load the data of the entire row" as others said - `count(*)` is always the fastest or one of the fastest options while `count(fieldname)` *could* be slower, depending on what field is given.

**EDIT**:
[the documantation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) says:

> COUNT(*) is optimized to return very quickly [...]. This optimization applies only to MyISAM tables only

read on the documentation for more information about this topic.

**Important note:** `count(*)` returns to total count of rows while `count(fieldname)` returns the count of rows there that given field isn't `NULL`. this is logically consistent as with `*` mysql can't know wich `NULL`-values to leave out. always think of this when doing `count()` as it *may* have a bic impact on the result.

Comment: Can you add a definitive article link that backs upo your first statement? – gbn 3 mins ago edit

Comment: an explanation for the downvote would be really nice. to quote the FAQ: "If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong" (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette)

Comment: The downvote is because your first statement is wrong. COUNT(*) and COUNT(table_field_name) can give different results because of NULLs.

Comment: thats whats stated some lines below. but `count(*)` and `count(primary_key)` wich i was saying won't make a difference really **can't** make a difference as a primary key should't be null (and, as far as i know, a primary can't be null, even if you try). about `count(*)`/`count(normal_field)` i'm just saying `count(*)` wont ever be slower, wich is also true.