# why mysql count(*) has better performance than count(id)

Tags: mysql

At first I want compare count(*) and count(id), which has better performance?

mysql version

```
5.6.21-1~dotdeb.1-log
```

table info

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `is_availability` (`is_availability`,`is_del`)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48993819 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

1. compare without where condition

   ```
   select count(*) from op_log;
   +----------+
   | count(*) |
   +----------+
   | 48989975 |
   +----------+
   1 row in set (10.02 sec)

   select count(id) from op_log ;
   +-----------+
   | count(id) |
   +-----------+
   |  48989990 |
   +-----------+
   1 row in set (12.05 sec)
   ```

`count(*)` better than `count(id)`

2. compare with where condition

   ```
   select count(*) from op_log where is_availability=1;
   +----------+
   | count(*) |
   +----------+
   | 48990038 |
   +----------+
   1 row in set (15.86 sec)
   select count(id) from op_log where is_availability=1;
   +-----------+
   | count(id) |
   +-----------+
   |  48990096 |
   +-----------+
   1 row in set (17.13 sec)
   ```

   `count(*)` still better than `count(id)`

So if I could draw the conclusion that `count(*)` has better performance than `count(id)` and why is this?

From `High Performance MySQL`, I got

> if mysql knows some col cannot be NULL, it will optimize count(col) to count(*) internally

So I suspect that the time spend more is used to do this optimization work.

Comment: How is `id` defined?

Comment: Search is your friend: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mysql+count+performance&t=ffsb - there are plenty of blog posts covering this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [whats faster, count(\*) or count(table\_field\_name) in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515531/whats-faster-count-or-counttable-field-name-in-mysql)

Comment: @Matthew PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Comment: maybe is duplicate, but it does not explain why `count(*)` better than `count(id)`

Answer (score 11):

Often `COUNT(*)` would have marginally better performance.  `COUNT(id)` needs to check if `id` is not `NULL` for it to work.  That means that it needs to read the value (as well as the small overhead for checking `NULL`ness).

I would expect the timings to be the same in most databases when `id` is a clustered primary key.  However, perhaps the MySQL optimizer doesn't bother avoiding the `NULL` check even for columns that are declared `NOT NULL`.

Note:  when doing timings you have to be very careful about starting with a cold cache.  In your case, the faster query seems to be the first run, so caching doesn't seem a likely explanation for the difference in performance.

Comment: Yeah, From High Performance MySQL, I got: "if mysql knows some col cannot be NULL, it will optimize count(col) to count(*) internally". 
So I suspect that the time spend more is used to do this optimization work.

Answer (score 5):

COUNT(*) will count all rows of your table

COUNT(column) will count non-NULLs columns only of your table.

You can check this [article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/):

> The thing is count(*) query can use covering index even while
>   count(col) can’t. Of course you can extend index to be (i,val) and get
>   query to be index covered again but I would use this workaround only
>   if you can’t change the query (ie it is third party application) or in
>   case column name is in the query for reason, and you really need count
>   of non-NULL values.